# how to edit the ngx_stream_proxy_module that create a empty file when the stream module is triggered?

Tags: nginx

Does anyone know how to amend the nginx source code for the ngx_stream_proxy_module? I'm trying to change the codes so that a file will be produced and inside will display the source IP address, among other things, when the server's stream module is activated.

as i am still new to nginx i am not sure how to start or where to look at. somebody help please!